# Which to use MS AL or ADAL in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I need someone to clarify which Api to use, it is MS AL or ADAL for Xamarin forms.
I need the Api to Access AzureAD. So which one is the right one.

Please help as this is important for me to work on Azure AD.

Update:
There are examples, but I really dont know which one is in used for xamarin forms. There is not much info I can find. Please help so that I can start coding and try it out and get back here for the problem encountered.

is ADAL deprecated or no longer supported?

Answer (score 1):

ADAL is for Azure AD's v1 endpoint, and MSAL is for the newer v2 endpoint.
The protocols have had some changes, so that's why the new library.

You can get an idea what is different here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare.

To boil it down:

1. Do you want to support personal Microsoft accounts (i.e. not organizational Azure AD accounts)? If yes, you must use v2
2. Do you need to use an API that is not yet supported by v2? Use v1

If you only need to support organizational accounts, v1 works fine.
Remember that at the moment apps registered via the Azure Portal are v1 apps.
V2 apps have a separate portal still, though they are moving it to Azure Portal too.

Comment: ADAL has problem with lower version of Android like 4.0 and other 4.0 something.  After first login, the subsequent login will stuck at Page "Bring you to your Organization Sign-In". Do you have the solution?

Comment: I don't sadly :( That sounds quite weird.

Comment: It will be good if you try and give us feedback. Can I give you a link of sample app to try. This app use ADAL. Why you are not getting this problem? Will you share with me? https://solidbrain.com/2016/11/07/extending-xamarin-forms-app-with-azure-ad-authentication/  (sample app)

Comment: any luck with the Sample app. Please advise your solution so that it will benefit people who has this issue that I mentioned here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to check it today.

Comment: Hi @MilkBottle - what juunas posted above is correct when deciding which library to use. You can also open issues on the repos themselves if you are running into problems or need to contact the team directly. [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues) or [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues). We also have a variety of samples we can direct you to if that helps as well.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to which library to choose, the answer @juunas posted is correct. Once you have that figured out, there are a number of samples which use Xamarin.

Here is an [MSAL sample using Xamarin](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2).

And an [ADAL sample using Xamarin](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget)

And a [B2C sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) using Xamarin and MSAL

Or you can open an issue on the [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/) or [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) repos to get help, assistance, or questions answered, or use their respective wikis for more information about the libraries and how to use them.